# strange behavior of backspace in a running readline code

Tags: c++, terminal, readline, tmux, backspace

I wrote a c++ code with the `readline` library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  char* buf;
  while ((buf = readline(">> ")) != nullptr) {
    if (strlen(buf) > 0) add_history(buf);

    printf("[%s]\n", buf);
    free(buf);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code runs OK, but the problem is with the `backspace` key. When I make a mistake with the input and trying to remove a character with the key, instead of removing the last character, it gives a space. Originally

```
>> Hellow
```

After hitting `backspace`, it gives me a space instead of removing `w`:

```
>> Hellow(there_is_a_space_here!)
```

I'm working in bash using tmux and this strange behavior only appears when running this code with `readline`. Could anyone tell me how to fix this strange behavior of `backspace`?

**UPDATE**

The same behavior also appears when running the code on `tcsh`.

Comment: I don’t see any C++ here except `nullptr`. You could tweak locales to match your needs

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that's not the way to detect if your compiler supports [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr). It's a keyword and not a preprocessor macro. You should check the `__cplusplus` macro to see that it's greater or equal to `201103L` (which is the value for C++11).

Comment: Can you use the backspace key in other programs running it tmux, like e.g. bash?

Comment: Also look for strange things in your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry about that `nullptr`, it's removed now!

Comment: @n.m. `backspace` behaves normally anywhere except for any codes using `readline`. could you be a bit more specific what we're looking for in `.bashrc`/`.inputrc`?

Comment: No idea but try `INPUTRC=/dev/null ./yourprogram`

Comment: @n.m. `INPUTRC=/dev/null ./myprogram` didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: So it's something else, not inputrc. Does readline work without tmux?

Comment: @n.m. the code is compiled and works perfectly in `tcsh` without tmux but the `backspace` behavior persists.

Comment: Have you solved this problem？After moving the libreadline.so, I ran into the same problem.

Comment: I faced same issue and could not find a solution, then I replaced readline with linenoise. Backspace issue does not happen with linenoise.